# What does #define Terminal ((arc*)1) mean？

Tags: c++

`arc` is a structure at [maxflow](http://code.google.com/p/graphcuts/source/browse/trunk/external/graphcut/maxflow.cpp?r=2) ,what does the `1` stand for?

Comment: `1` is just an arbitrary integer that is highly unlikely to be a memory address stored in an actual valid pointer. This way, `Terminal` is a special value that is distinct from `NULL` and from any valid `arc*` pointer the program might obtain.

Comment: This is the exact answer I need. Thank you. Is there any other specific book or chapter illustrating this? Dois

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you should just write an answer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I added a CW answer which basically reflects your comment, if you wish to elaborate please feel free. It is always frustrating to come to a question an realize there is already an answer in the comments at least now there is an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the `maxflow.cpp` they want a *pointer value* for `Terminal` that is distinct from `NULL` yet is very unlikely to ever be a valid pointer value and `1` fits that role well.