# What does this macro mean?

Tags: c, macros

```
#define TRASHIT(x)  do {(x) = (void *)-1;} while (0)
```

I meet this macro in the `sys/queue.h`, and google it but find nothing useful about this.
This macro set the pointer `x` to `(void *)-1`, but what does the `(void *)-1` mean? What is the difference between this and `NULL`?

Comment: `NULL` is typically `0x0` while this value is `0xffffffff`.

Comment: Lots of "trash" values around, 0xdeadbeef is popular for example.  NULL is not trashy enough.

Comment: Perhaps it is just meant to be an [invalid pointer value different from NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25635255/1708801)

Comment: is there a reason why it's in a do while loop that only executes the code once?

Comment: @HansPassant or 0xBADC0FFEE0DDF00D for 64 bit.

Comment: @awk you can read this post regarding the `do while loop` usage.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is meant to be an invalid pointer different from `NULL` to be used as sort of flag or indication of error. We can find an example of this kind of us in the [man page for shmat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat) it says (*emphasis mine*):

> On success shmat() returns the address of the attached shared memory
>   segment; **on error (void *) -1 is returned**, and errno is set to
>   indicate the cause of the error.

so in order to flag an error `shmat` returns `(void *) -1` which is an invalid pointer with a distinct value.

The question [Is ((void *) -1) a valid address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13306914/1708801) deals with the validity of such a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It's setting `x` to a pointer value for which dereferencing is probably *undefined behaviour* (as it's unlikely you own the memory, if any, at that address).

The `do` `while(0)` loop is a fairly standard idiom used when writing macros: it compels the user to append a semicolon when using it and can help control the scope of variables introduced in the macro's implementation. Of course, the statement within the loop is executed exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

The standard does not prescribe any behavior for

```
(void*)-1;
```

except to *suggest* making the mapping between integral numbers and pointers natural for the underlying platforms addressing model.

Thus, if your implementation allows creation of invalid pointers, that will likely be a void-pointer value with all bits set.

A null pointer is represented in source by a constant integral expression (possibly cast to `void*`), or in some implementation-defined manner.
On most modern systems, it's a void-pointer with all bits clear.

So, while the two **can be identical**, that's **unlikely**, especially on modern systems.
Also, that second one is very **unlikely to be a valid pointer**.

Answer (score 0):

It's just for returning an error type, I think, just as below:

```
#define TRASHIT(x)  do {(x) = (void *)-1;} while (0)

void* foo (void) {

    void* ret;

    if(fail) {
        TRASHIT(x);
    }
    else {
        sometingelse(x);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I think [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) is more on the right track here.